# How to use getResources() in ViewPager Adapter?

Tags: android, resources, android-viewpager

I have tried EVERY SINGLE solution available on web and can not get this to work.

Please help me point out my error in this implementation of the `ViewPager` Adapter, error 'cannot resolve method `getResources()`' keeps showing up!

Here is my code of the relevant class (problem in the `getPageTitle` method):

```css
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    CharSequence Titles[]; 
    int NumbOfTabs; 

    
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);

        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

    }

@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(position == 0) 
        {
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        }
        else           
        {
            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
        }
    }

    private int[] imageResId = {
            R.drawable.social,
            R.drawable.artist
    };

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        // return tabTitles[position];
        Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
        image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(),                image.getIntrinsicHeight());
        SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return sb;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not call getResources() method like this it's method in Context class.
Send context to adapter like

```
private Context mContext;
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb, Context context) {
        super(fm);

        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;
this.mContext = context

    }
```

then call mContext.getResources(); like

```
Drawable image = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
```

Answer (score 0):

pass Context object to ViewPagerAdapter at the Constructor and :

pass Context object :

```
 Context my_context ;
 public ViewPagerAdapter(Context passed_context ,FragmentManager fm ... )           
 {
    this.my_context = passed_context ;
    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;
 }
```

then you can get this function by

```
my_context.getResources() ;
```